# pass variable from slider to flask

Tags: jquery, python, highcharts, flask

I would like to retrieve value from jquery slider and pass it to flask. That should trigger another function that extracts data from my database and generates Highcharts chart.

My HTML file:

```
 <form action="." class="form-inline" style="margin:10px" method="POST">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="station_id" name="station_id">
          <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Search">

  </form>
    <form method="post" action=".">
    <label for="amount-time" style="margin:10px">Time</label>
    <input type="text" name="amount-time" id="amount-time"  style="border: 0; color: #666666; font-weight: bold; width: 400px; margin:10px" value={{ time }}>
    <div id="slider-time" style="width: 400px; margin:10px"></div><br></form>
```

My jQuery code in HTML file:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#slider-time').slider({
        range: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 1430,
        step: 10,
        values: [540],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            var hours1 = Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 60);
            var minutes1 = ui.values[0] - (hours1 * 60);

            if(hours1.length < 10) hours1= '0' + hours;
            if(minutes1.length < 10) minutes1 = '0' + minutes;

            if(minutes1 == 0) minutes1 = '00';

            var hours2 = Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 60);
            var minutes2 = ui.values[1] - (hours2 * 60);

            if(hours2.length < 10) hours2= '0' + hours;
            if(minutes2.length < 10) minutes2 = '0' + minutes;

            if(minutes2 == 0) minutes2 = '00';

            jQuery('#amount-time').val(hours1+':'+minutes1 );
        }
    });
});
```

And finally my Flask function:

```
@app.route('/averages/', methods=['GET','POST'])

def averages(chartID = 'chart_ID', chart_type = 'column', chart_height = 500):
    station_id = request.form.get('station_id')
    time = request.form.get('amount-time')
    if request.form.get('station_id') == None:
        station_id = 1
        time = '09:00'
    else:
        station_id = request.form.get('station_id')

    if len(getInfoStation(int(station_id)).columns) == 0:
        station_info = "Incorrect station"
        flash("Incorrect station ID.")
    else:
        station_info = getInfoStation(int(station_id)).to_html(classes="table-condensed table-hover")
    chart = {"renderTo": chartID, "type": chart_type, "height": chart_height,}
    series =[{"name": 'Number of bikes', "data": averageDayHour(int(station_id), time)}]
    title = {"text": 'Average Bikes'}
    xAxis = {"categories": ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']}
    yAxis = {"title": {"text": 'Bikes'}}
    return render_template('averages.html', chartID=chartID, chart=chart, series=series, title=title, xAxis=xAxis, yAxis=yAxis, station_id=station_id, tables=[station_info], time=time)
```

As you can see there is another form (variable station_id) and it does correctly update the chart. It only works with the default time value of '09:00'. I am not sure what I am doing wrong...

Comment: I don't see station_id in your html.  You're getting 09:00 because that's what the application logic says to use if there's no station_id, which there isn't.

Comment: you're right. I missed the bit with another form. I updated it now.

Comment: It's the slider that causes problems. The station_id works fine. It starts with default value of 1 and when I enter ID into the form and click Search, it updates the chart. When I change slider's value there is no action.

Comment: check out highcharts jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-column-interactive/  To me I don't see where you're capturing the slider vals to route to the function in your jQuery.

Comment: Still, isn't that the problem with two separate forms? Have you tried to use just one `<form>` ? Maybe `request.form.get('amount-time')` always return `None`? Have you checked that value (or double checked)?

Comment: I merged both forms but it didn't help. I guess this is what happens - request.form.get('amount-time') always return None. I am not sure how to solve it though. I guess I need some 'default' values to pass into query when the page is loaded. I tried to do it with the first IF statement but doesn't work...